# Overload operator == for STL container

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, boost-any

I'm trying to remove a class object from `list<boost::any> l`

```
l.remove(class_type);
```

I tried writing something like this as a member function

```
bool operator == (const class_type &a) const //not sure about the arguments
{
   //return bool value
}
```

How would you write an overload function to remove an object of class from a std::list of `boost::any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your signature for `operator==` looks fine, overloading it for `class_type` isn't enough as `boost::any` doesn't magically use it. For removing elements however you can pass a predicate to `remove_if`, e.g.:

```
template<class T>
bool test_any(const boost::any& a, const T& to_test) {
    const T* t = boost::any_cast<T>(&a);
    return t && (*t == to_test);
}

std::list<boost::any> l = ...;
class_type to_test = ...;
l.remove_if(boost::bind(&test_any<class_type>, _1, to_test));
```

Comment: Nice idea.  That said, I'd reduce lines 2 and 3 to `return t && (*t == to_test);`